# wp_enqueue_style not adding version

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add version to style.css file but its not adding version to style.css infact not adding version to any of css files. here's my code

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyfifteen-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(),'1.0','all');
```

Does any body knows what is the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you mentioned that *none* if your stylesheets are getting versions I would suspect a plugin or the theme is filtering those URLs.

Try searching your theme and all plugins for any usage of the [`style_loader_src`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/style_loader_src/) filter. You may find the problem there.

Comment: Yes in function.php file I've this filter for both style and script. I tried to comment these two filters but version still won't come.

Comment: Are you running any caching plugins that might still be serving the previous markup? I'd also ensure this isn't happening in any plugins.

Comment: I've disabled w3 cache plugin.

Comment: As noted here remove_query_arg is another possible source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805009/wordpress-css-and-js-version-numbers-not-working

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me nuts for days! Starter theme had `style_loader_src` filter.

Comment: Still a useful answer