# can't change version using wp_enqueue_style or anything

Tags: css, wordpress, caching

I've enqueued a style sheet using

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'home-custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
'/css/style.css');
```

in my child theme
then when I tried to modify it, I've realised that wordpress gave it an automatic version, which now I can't change.

I have tried modifying the enqueue code adding a version,

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'home-custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
'/css/style.css' , array(), '30140222');
```

also tried dequeuing it and enqueuing it again, and deleting the file and readding it in the folder but nothing is working.
except `null`.

For now I made a hard refresh (bypassing my cache) pressing **Ctrl + F5**  in the browser, cause I'm on the local host, but still need an answer to use it on the server.

Comment: Have you checked whether it's enqueued twice (or is registered with the same) name before you enqueue it? For debugging purposes, you might extend WP_Styles and use a cusom add() method to see exactly when and where that style is added.

Comment: unfortunately it's not only one stylesheet, but all stylesheets that I have added, so the problem is not in the name.

Comment: Do you have any optimization/caching plugin that maybe overrides WP_Styles and removes query parameters? Have you tried disabling plugins one by one to see whether it works?

Comment: It finally worked when I disabled the "Child Theme Configurator" plugin. thank you.

Comment: it is possible there is another function that strips the version numbers. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805009/wordpress-css-and-js-version-numbers-not-working

Comment: You can disable Chrome cache when opening DevTools
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392441/stop-chrome-caching-my-js-files

Answer (score 2):

*heads-up the following applies to scripts too, just replace `style` with `script` and you're good to go*

The problem is that you're trying to modify an already registered style. See, when you call `wp_enqueue_style()`, the style is registered and enqueued at the same time(vs calling `wp_register_style()` and then `wp_enqueue_style()` which I recommend).

However, if a style has already been registered, when you try to enqueue it the extra parameters are not used, they're just ignored.

What you need to do is the following( make sure to fill in the correct parameters in the `wp_register_style()` below):

```
wp_deregister_style( 'my-style' );
wp_register_style( 'my-style', ... );
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style' );
```

This first deregisters the still you want to modify and then registers it again with the modified parameters. This will work with styles that are used as a dependency or have dependencies of their own, because dependencies are resolved at the time the style is being loaded on the page and not when it's registered/enqueued.

For what you're trying to achieve though, I would personally just register whatever scripts and styles I want to override in the child theme before the parent theme does it. That way you won't have to deregisters and register them. Here's an example(part of it is the sample parent theme's code):

```
function parent_theme_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'example-style', get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/css/example.css', array(), 'v1.0.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'parent_theme_enqueue_scripts', 10 );

function child_theme_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_register_style( 'example-style', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/css/example.css', array(),'v1.2.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_enqueue_scripts', 5 );
```

The important thing to notice here is the priority on `child_theme_enqueue_scripts` - it's lower than that of `parent_theme_enqueue_scripts`. Also note that we're not directly enqueue-ing the style, but instead we're just registering it. That's in order to not mess up the loading order of styles(in case the parent theme enqueues multiple styles but doesn't use dependencies to do that).

Comment: tried to deregister then register it again but it didn't work, also tried to register them before all the parent styles, like the second method, but it didn't work either. and I really don't think it's name is already taken before or registered by the parent theme.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to search your `themes` & `plugins` folders for functions that modify your enqueued styles and scripts.

I was looking for lines containing `style_loader_src` or `ver=` and discovered a plugin called "Child Theme Configuratior" that was the culprit.

Turned that plugin off and everything started to work as expected.

Comment: This is what's screwing me over. I couldn't find anything in regards to why it wasn't working until I stumbled across this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this function in `function.php`

```
function wpa() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'home-custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' , array(), '30140222' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa');
```